# TextWatcher incorrect selection from database

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-spinner

[image]My textwatcher is gives me incorrect output in Android Studio. Can anyone suggest me the workaround to solve this issue.

Requirment. "If the course title starts with the user input in edittext then its shows in spinner(Data from database)"

Note: I am using single spinner for multiple purpose 1. Selecting spinner contects 2. showing the spinner value based on edittext user input

My codings.

```js
package com.bar.example.myapplication;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CourseSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private DBHelper db;
  private List < Course > allCoursesList;
  private List < Offering > allOfferingsList;
  private List < Offering > filteredOfferingsList;

  private EditText courseTitleEditText;
  private Spinner ok;
  private ListView offeringsListView;

  // private selectedInstructorName selectedInstructorName;
  private InstructorSpinnerAdapter instructorSpinnerAdapter;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_search);

    deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.importCoursesFromCSV("courses.csv");

    db.importOfferingsFromCSV("offerings.csv");

    allOfferingsList = db.getAllOfferings();
    filteredOfferingsList = new ArrayList < > (allOfferingsList);

    allCoursesList = db.getAllCourses();

    courseTitleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseTitleEditText);
    courseTitleEditText.addTextChangedListener(courseTitleTextWatcher);

    ok = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);



    // offeringListAdapter = new OfferingListAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);
    // ok.setAdapter(offeringListAdapter);
    instructorSpinnerAdapter = new InstructorSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);

    ArrayAdapter < String > instructorSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
      (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAllCourse());
    ok.setAdapter(instructorSpinnerAdapter);

    ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);


  }
  private String[] getAllCourse() {
    String[] instructorNames = new String[allCoursesList.size() + 1];
    instructorNames[0] = "[Select Course]";
    for (int i = 1; i < instructorNames.length; i++) {
      instructorNames[i] = allCoursesList.get(i - 1).getTitle();
    }
    return instructorNames;
  }

  public TextWatcher courseTitleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
      String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
      if (input.equals("")) {

      } else {
        String name = ok.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(CourseSearchActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
        Offering offering;
        for (int j = 0; j < allOfferingsList.size(); j++) {
          // If the course title starts with the user input,
          // add it to the listAdapter
          offering = allOfferingsList.get(j);
          Course course = offering.getCourse();
          if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(input)) {
            instructorSpinnerAdapter.add(offering);
            instructorSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ok.setSelection(instructorSpinnerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


    }
  };



  public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener instructorSpinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
      String selectedInstructorName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
      if (selectedInstructorName.equals("[Select Instructor]")) {
        instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
        for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList)
          instructorSpinnerAdapter.add(offering);


      } else {

        instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();

      }

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView) {
      adapterView.setSelection(0);
      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Why?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  };

  public void reset(View view) {
    courseTitleEditText.setText("");
    ok.setSelection(0);
  }


}
```

as per suggestion

```js
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
  String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
  if (input.equals("")) {

  } else {
    String name = ok.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //Toast.makeText(CourseSearchActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
    Offering offering;
    for (int j = 0; j < allOfferingsList.size(); j++) {
      // If the course title starts with the user input,
      // add it to the listAdapter
      offering = allOfferingsList.get(j);
      Course course = offering.getCourse();
      if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(input)) {
        if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(input))
          instructorSpinnerAdapter.add(offering);
        instructorSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ok.setSelection(instructorSpinnerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

error

```js
04-26 10:35:46.394 31756-31756/com.bar.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bar.example.myapplication, PID: 31756
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
        at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:571)
        at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:234)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:285)
        at com.bar.example.myapplication.CourseSearchActivity$1.onTextChanged(CourseSearchActivity.java:95)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8187)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8249)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10371)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1208)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:578)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:509)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:508)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:844)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:617)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:408)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:93)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Current view is ..

[image]

instead of this i need to enter database x and spinner should y screen follows

[image]

my database follows.

[image]

I am trying to get single input and multiple output. screen example

[image]

revised code

```js
public TextWatcher courseTitleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

  }
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) ok.getAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = (ArrayAdapter) ok1.getAdapter();
    adapter.clear();
    adapter1.clear();
    if (input.equals("")) {
      adapter.addAll(getAllCourse());
      adapter1.addAll(getAllCourse());
    } else {
      Course course;

      for (int j = 0; j < allCoursesList.size(); j++) {
        // If the course title starts with the user input,
        // add it to the listAdapter
        course = allCoursesList.get(j);
        if (course.getAlpha().toLowerCase().startsWith(input) || course.getNumber().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {
          adapter.add(course.getTitle());
          adapter1.add(course.getNumber());
        }
      }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (adapter.getCount() != 0) ok.setSelection(0);
    if (adapter1.getCount() != 0) ok1.setSelection(0);
  }
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


  }
};

public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener instructorSpinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String selectedInstructorName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    if (selectedInstructorName.equals("[Select Instructor]")) {
      instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
      for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList)
        instructorSpinnerAdapter.add(offering);


    } else {

      instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();

    }

  }


  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView) {
    adapterView.setSelection(0);

    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Why?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
};
```

```js
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_search);

  deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
  db = new DBHelper(this);
  db.importCoursesFromCSV("courses.csv");

  db.importOfferingsFromCSV("offerings.csv");
  Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
  allOfferingsList = db.getAllOfferings();
  filteredOfferingsList = new ArrayList < > (allOfferingsList);

  allCoursesList = db.getAllCourses();

  courseTitleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseTitleEditText);
  courseTitleEditText.addTextChangedListener(courseTitleTextWatcher);

  ok = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  ok1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

  // offeringListAdapter = new OfferingListAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);
  // ok.setAdapter(offeringListAdapter);
  instructorSpinnerAdapter = new InstructorSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);

  ArrayAdapter < String > instructorSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAllCourse());
  ok.setAdapter(instructorSpinnerAdapter);
  ok1.setAdapter(instructorSpinnerAdapter);
  ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);

  ok1.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);
}
```

it works but some time not . could you check and advise...

error...attached[image]

Another Condition:

Select spinner2 selection based on spinner screenshot attached. how to swap the same . pls advise.
[image]

Comment: Try change: "if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(input)) {" to "if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {" Hope that helps!

Comment: still same no improvement pasted above with suggested..

Comment: application crashed if i enter anything in edittext .error attached

Comment: Hi @I_A_Mok any clue.

Comment: @I_A_Mok   thank you .. but error in "cannot resolve symbol 'length'.

Comment: thank you searching not showing name but showing something else. attached screenshot @I_A_Mok

Comment: now search ok. but spinner selection is not functioning.... attached screenshot..@I_A_Mok

Comment: @I_A_Mok any clue ?   if not possible then reset spinner button do so that spinner selection will working....

Comment: Change "adapter.add(getAllCourse());" to "adapter.addAll(getAllCourse());" in OnTextChanged().

Comment: Bravo man it works ....Salute for your intellectual knowledge... @I_A_Mok

Comment: @I_A_Mok i need you help where i am searching with x  in edittext and result should be y in spinner. details attached can you help

Comment: Replace "if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {" with "if (course.getNumber().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {". I assume that your Course class has a method getNumber() for return the "Number" as String. Otherwise pls post your Course class. If this work, you can even combine the two: "if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(input) || course.getNumber().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {". Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @I_A_Mok  great it works and rocks.....

Comment: @I_A_Mok can you help me with another one. paste above

Comment: adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged(); is missing.

Comment: tried but same, any other suggestion...@I_A_Mok

Comment: @I_A_Mok can you suggest me with . spinner swap. I mean spinner2 selection based on spinner1

Comment: @I_A_Mok thanks it works, Please keep the same in answer to vote for your initiative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_search);

    deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.importCoursesFromCSV("courses.csv");

    db.importOfferingsFromCSV("offerings.csv");
    Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    allOfferingsList = db.getAllOfferings();
    filteredOfferingsList = new ArrayList <> (allOfferingsList);

    allCoursesList = db.getAllCourses();

    courseTitleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseTitleEditText);
    courseTitleEditText.addTextChangedListener(courseTitleTextWatcher);

    ok = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ok1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    // offeringListAdapter = new OfferingListAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);
    // ok.setAdapter(offeringListAdapter);
    instructorSpinnerAdapter = new InstructorSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);

    // The two spinners need to have different adapters as they will use different datasets.
    ok.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAllCourse()));
    ok1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAllCourseNumber()));
    // The two spinner can have same listener.
    ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);
    ok1.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);
}

private ArrayList<String> getAllCourse() {
    ArrayList<String> instructorNames = new ArrayList<>();
    instructorNames.add("[Select Course]");
    for (int i = 0; i < allCoursesList.size(); i++) {
        instructorNames.add(allCoursesList.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    return instructorNames;
}

private ArrayList<String> getAllCourseNumber() {
    ArrayList<String> instructorNames = new ArrayList<>();
    instructorNames.add("[Select Course]");
    for (int i = 0; i < allCoursesList.size(); i++) {
        instructorNames.add(allCoursesList.get(i).getNumber());
    }
    return instructorNames;
}

public TextWatcher courseTitleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) ok.getAdapter();
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = (ArrayAdapter) ok1.getAdapter();
        adapter.clear();
        adapter1.clear();
        if (input.equals("")) {
            adapter.addAll(getAllCourse());
            adapter1.addAll(getAllCourseNumber());
        } else {
            Course course;
            for (int j=0; j < allCoursesList.size(); j++) {
                // If the course alpha/number starts with the user input,
                // add it to the listAdapter
                course = allCoursesList.get(j);
                if (course.getAlpha().toLowerCase().startsWith(input) || course.getNumber().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {
                    adapter.add(course.getTitle());
                    adapter1.add(course.getNumber());
                }
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (adapter.getCount() != 0) ok.setSelection(0);
        if (adapter1.getCount() != 0) ok1.setSelection(0);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
};

public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener instructorSpinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //String selectedInstructorName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        // No matter which spinner is selected, get item from the ok [Title] spinner.
        String selectedInstructorName = ok.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        if (selectedInstructorName.equals("[Select Instructor]")) {
            instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
            for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList)
                instructorSpinnerAdapter.add(offering);
        } else {
            instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        adapterView.setSelection(0);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Why?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

I am not sure why use getAlpha() in TextWatcher as you show that alpha is always CS. If the code does not work, then in getAllCourseNumber() change **allCoursesList.get(i).getNumber()** to **allCoursesList.get(i).getAlpha()**, so we can have a list of alpha for checking.

Hope that helps!

Updated the OnItemSelectedListener:

```
    public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener instructorSpinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // Sync the selection of the two spinners.
        if(adapterView.getId() == R.id.spinner1){
            ok1.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
            ok1.setSelection(i);
            ok1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }else{
            ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
            ok.setSelection(i);
            ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        // No matter which spinner is selected, get item from the ok [Title] spinner.
        String selectedInstructorName = ok.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        if (selectedInstructorName.equals("[Select Instructor]")) {
            instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
            for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList)
                instructorSpinnerAdapter.add(offering);
        } else {
            instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        adapterView.setSelection(0);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Why?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Updated the OnItemSelectedListener! Added a block of if...else.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Try the code below:

with new code while searching following output in spinner while searching

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter)ok.getAdapter();
    adapter.clear();
    if (input.equals("")) {
        adapter.add(getAllCourse());
    } else {
        Course course;
        for (int j = 0; j < allCoursesList.size(); j++) {
            // If the course title starts with the user input,
            // add it to the listAdapter
            course = allCoursesList.get(j);
            if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {
                adapter.add(course.getTitle());
            }
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(adapter.getCount() != 0) ok.setSelection(0);
}
```

CHANGE getAllCourse() to use ArrayList instead of String[].

```
private ArrayList<String> getAllCourse() {
    ArrayList<String> instructorNames = new ArrayList<>();
    instructorNames.add("[Select Course]");
    for (int i = 0; i < allCoursesList.size(); i++) {
        instructorNames.add(allCoursesList.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    return instructorNames;
}
```

now search ok. but spinner selection is not functioning.... attached screenshot..[image]

Comment: Updated the answer! Changed getAllCourse().

Comment: Updated the answer! Both mehtods had made changes.

Comment: thank you @I_A_Mok searching not showing name but showing something else. attached screenshot

Comment: Updated the answer! Changes in onTextChanged().

Comment: now search ok. but spinner selection is not functioning.... attached screenshot..@I_A_Mok